# SQL injection theory

Tags: php, mysql, security, sql-injection, database-theory

I'm using ORM layer in databases all the time, so I don't mind about SQL injections, but a friend gave me this task and I still have no idea how to solve it.

I know the PHP script just checks if the return of the query is != null (username matching to entered username & password is found).

The query itself in PHP looks like:

```
$sql = "SELECT name FROM users WHERE name='".$name. "' AND password='".$password. "'";
```

What's the best way to archieve a return of this query != null OR retrieving valid login data (username & password). The password is stored plain in database. I know storing plain is bad and I know using PDO is good, but I have no idea how to solve this funny task he gave me, maybe because I use PDO all the time.

Comment: Storing plain passwords in the database is a **big** no-no. They really should be hashed. Also, consider the case where someone inputs `'; DROP TABLE users` into this statement. Whoops, and your table is *gone*. This means you need to escape the userinputs (*never trust user input*) or use prepared statements. I recommend the latter.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I prevent SQL-injection in PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)

Comment: It's not how to prevent a SQL injection, as I told I use db abstraction layers, it's more theory.

Comment: `"so I don't mind about SQL injections"` - Attackers love that kind of confidence.  `"The query itself in PHP looks like [...]"` - And *that*, my friend, is a SQL injection vulnerability.  `"The password is stored plain in database."` - Attackers love that, too.  ...  More to the point, what are you actually asking?  What are you trying to "solve" here?

Comment: You've been asked to break your ORM managed db, or you've been given a query and tell how it can be hacked? something like "if I use mysql_* functions, and I do this...." irrespectful of what you're actuallyt doing in your code?

Comment: "What's the best way to archieve a return of this query" <-- is this your question?

Comment: also while using an orm layer you should still validate user input since you dont want user names like /*a457--?..You should validate user input no matter of sql injection..

Comment: @em validation has nothing to do with security

Comment: @DamienPirsy Do you mean an attack can't be done using current forms or these guys are wrong..https://www.owasp.org/index.php/SQL_Injection_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet

Comment: @ern I repeat, VALIDATION has little to do with injection. Allowing an username to contain only alphanumerical chars or letting it have spaces doesn't chang anything. `*a457-?` is a perfectly valid username if the system allows it. Also, `'''''''''''''''` is. I suspect there's a misunderstanding around the concept of "validation", so I'm not going further in the discussion

Answer (score 3):

Say we have these two input variables:

```
$name = "iam";
$password = "aninjection";
```

Which results in this query:

```
$sql = "SELECT name FROM users WHERE name='iam' AND password='aninjection'";
```

And let's say now we add this to the `$password` variable:

```
$password = "aninjection' OR 1='1";
```

Which results in:

```
$sql = "SELECT name FROM users WHERE name='iam' AND password='aninjection' OR 1='1'";
```

This query will now result in `true` and show every name from the user table.
This is of course a basic example. We could also do more harm by dropping entire tables.

Comment: Is there a way to retrieve password of a user? Getting the list of usernames wasn't that hard.

Answer (score 1):

If you wanted to retrieve passwords you would inject

```
$name = "whatever";
$password = "' OR '1'='1' UNION ALL SELECT password from users;--";
```

This would then make the query

```
SELECT name FROM users WHERE name='whatever' AND password='' OR '1'='1' UNION ALL SELECT password from users;--'
```

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34175413/413180) for how an attacker would start to work this out from injecting into the query.